# failing access data from an array and convert it in pdf

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch data from a database and converting it in a Pdf File but the pdf file is empty it doesn't display the database elements the problem is when I get to the variable $res inside the while cycle I get the array but I can't access it . I don't get what am I doing wrong, can you help me?

```
  <?php
  /**
   * @package     tool_report
   * @author      Marko
   * @license     http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
   */

   require('../blocks/bbbreport/fpdf/fpdf.php');
   ob_start(); //
   require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config.php');
   defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

   $PAGE->set_url(new moodle_url('/course/manage.php'));
   $PAGE->set_context(\context_system::instance());
   $PAGE->set_title(get_string('manage_reports', 'tool_report'));

   global $DB;

   echo $OUTPUT->header();

   $conn = new mysqli($CFG->dbhost, $CFG->dbuser, $CFG->dbpass, $CFG->dbname);


   if ($conn->connect_errno) {
       echo $conn->connect_error;
       return;
   }


   $sql = " SELECT *
            FROM mdl_bigbluebuttonbn
          ";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $res = [];

   $pdf = new FPDF();
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->SetFont('Courier','B',16);
   $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Course ID', '1', '0', 'C');
   $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Course TYPE', '1', '0', 'C');
   $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Course COURSE', '1', '0', 'C');
   $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Course NAME', '1', '0', 'C');
   ?><?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                   
      **$res[]= $row;
      var_dump($res['name]);**
     ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $res['id'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $res['type'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $res['course'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $res['name'] ?></td>
     </tr>
   <?php
     var_dump($res);die();

    }
   }
   ob_end_clean();
   $pdf->Output();
   $conn->close();

   echo $OUTPUT->footer();
   ?>
```

Comment: [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) does not work with HTML.

Comment: These two lines contain few syntax errors `**$res[]= $row;
      var_dump($res['name]);**`

Comment: these one $res[]= $row;       var_dump($res['name])?    Can you explain me?

Comment: `var_dump($res['name]);` has a typo (a missing `'`) it should be `var_dump($res['name']);`

Comment: `echo $res['id']` also will make no sense, because $res is an array of rows, it won't contain those indexes directly. `echo $row['id']` would make more sense.

Comment: (P.S. As an idea for testing, maybe just output your HTML to the browser or a text file, without trying to put it in a PDF, then you can check the basic output is correct without worying about whether the PDF creation process is causing an issue.)

Comment: Thanks but It's not that, when I try to do the var_dump it gives NULL, If I do the var_dump of $res I get the array but if I do the var_dump of $res['name] I get NULL

Comment: You mean `var_dump($res);` returns null? That's impossible, even if you never add any data to it after the first declaratio - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f32d7827129aee5980bb4a38fd5df72f3741e7b ...it always shows it as an empty array, at the very least.

Comment: If I do the var_dump of $res I get the array but if I do the var_dump of $res['name] I get NULL

Comment: However if you mean that `var_dump($res['name'])` is null, then go back to my earlier comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027855/failing-access-data-from-an-array-and-convert-it-in-pdf#comment121997577_69027855 - it's the same issue. (And if you're var_dumping the whole of $res successfully, then looking at the structure should be helping you to see why - look what indexes $res actually has: I expect they are 0, 1, 2, etc, not names. The named indexes are _within_ those numbered indexes - i.e. they are arrays within arrays)

Comment: yes Tht's right,  thanks